# HTTP 200 Response yet there's no valid content?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, iis-6, http-headers, xmlhttprequest

I've been looking into an issue i'm experiencing when posting to a server, specifically when opening a Word file from the returned response.

An XMLHttpRequest object via JavaScript is being used to send data back to the clients machine from the web server using the .open and .send functions - the responseText having the resultant XML within.

After looking in Fiddler this request shows the following:

[image: Fiddler view]

However you can see there's the red symbol, looking at the Fiddler documentation this means that the ["Session was aborted by the client, Fiddler, or the Server."](http://www.fiddler2.com/Fiddler/help/ui.asp).

Furthermore the header for the response appears to be correct:

[image: HTTP Response]
[image: Header]

What would cause the aforementioned behaviour? The browser is not displaying any visible script errors (IE8) and i've made sure that JavaScript errors are not supressed. Looking at the TextView filter in Fiddler you can see the Word data, mentions of Fonts and styles etc.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: pre-word 2007 documents are binary, not xml.

Comment: Are you sending the request to the same domain or to an external one? Maybe the same-origin policy applies in your case.

Comment: @DanielA.White It appears the error occurs regardless of the content type, although a word document (2007) caught my attention this time.

FelixKling -  The request is being sent to the same domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears the issue was due to a mis-registered MXSML .DLL, after re-registering the DLL in question functionality was restored.